# Ordering by the percentage of a word in a string

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I have a common database and I want to select only the items where "str1" is in the columns "nom" and I thought to order it by the most "significant" to the least "significant".

I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    films 
WHERE   LOCATE(:name, nom) != 0 
LIMIT   0, 10 
ORDER BY (LENGTH(nom)/LENGTH(:name))
```

`:name` is `$_POST['name']` - the field given by the user in a formula.

Does anyone know how I can do this?  (I am using PHP and PDO with a prepared request)

Comment: It may not be working because of the integer division.  Try changing the `ORDER BY` statement to `ORDER BY (LENGTH(nom) * 1.0) / (LENGTH(:name) * 1.0)`

Comment: It worked !
Do you think this is the best ordering way for a research function on a website ?

Comment: I've never really done anything like that before, so I don't really know what the best way would be.